# How to get seller name from Seller Id using Amazon MWS API

Tags: amazon-mws

I got the PriceChangedNotification by http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/subscriptions/Subscriptions_NotificationType.html.

It returns Seller ID of new offer per ASIN.

I need to get the Seller's name by Seller ID.

How can I do that?

Comment: i think there is no api for this ...well you need to scrape the data by sellers ids using CURL request..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we did is took a list of the sellerID's and did a scrape using a URL like this: https://www.amazon.com/sp?seller=xxxxxxxxxxx for each seller id.  Then pull the seller name out of the resulting html (look for id=sellerName) and stored that in a table.  Then when I get a PriceChangedNotification, I join to my sellers table to produce my reports, or whatever else I may need.

Answer (score 0):

Keepa has a nice API that can get this for you and lots of other things that MWS won't. It's not free, but it might be worth it if you have a bunch of things you want to get from Amazon and don't want to scrape everything yourself. Unfortunately, it seems MWS keeps becoming more restrictive.

https://keepa.com/#!discuss/t/request-seller-information/790?u=keepa

Answer (score 0):

The rabbit hole brought me here. Considering I spent an hour googling and testing, here it is so the next one may save some time.

```
import requests
import urllib.request
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


seller_id = ""

s = requests.Session()
url = f"https://www.amazon.co.uk/sp?seller={seller_id}"
headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0',
    "Cookie":'i18n-prefs=GBP;' # won't work without this cookie 
}
r = s.get(url, headers=headers)
# >> print(r) --> response 200

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
soup.find("h1", {"id": "sellerName"}).text
```

important things to note: Amazon blocks scrapers, you'll need to simulate a http request. Use postman to ping the particular URL you are interested in and look at what headers it sends, in particular what cookies it sends. In this case my request wouldn't work without the i18n-prefs cookie.